# SQL exception using MyBatis

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis, dao

I got a problem. When running this MyBatis select:

```
<select id="findIdByCode" resultType="long">
        select USER_ID from PWD_REST_CODE
        where RESTORATION_CODE = #{code}
        and current_date between date_from and DATE_FROM + interval #{interval} second
</select>
```

I got EJB Exception:

```
EJB exception occurred during invocation from home or business: 
com.project.auth.ejb.data.UserManagerBean_rdl8zk_Intf generated exception: 
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ### Error querying 
database. Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: неверное 
завершение SQL-предложения ### The error may exist in 
com/project/auth/dao/UserDAO.xml ### The error may involve 
defaultParameterMap ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### SQL: 
select USER_ID from PWD_REST_CODE where RESTORATION_CODE = ? and current_date 
between date_from and DATE_FROM + interval ? second ### Cause: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: неверное завершение SQL-предложения
```

(`неверное завершение SQL-предложения` stands for `SQL command not properly ended`)

But when I run exactly the same query in database manager:

```
    select USER_ID from PWD_REST_CODE
    where RESTORATION_CODE = '217799dfHj'
    and current_date between date_from and DATE_FROM + interval '86400' second
```

I got the deserved id (`user_id, 5`). Why it happens?

Comment: `interval '86400' second` is a bit different from `interval 86400 second` what you use in MyBasic. I suppose that because the type is NUMBER MyBatis doesn't add the quotes around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marmite Bomber correctly wrote in comments you can't use number in `INTERVAL` literal. Use `numToDSInterval` function to convert number to interval:

```
<select id="findIdByCode" resultType="long">
     select USER_ID from PWD_REST_CODE
     where RESTORATION_CODE = #{code}
         and current_date between date_from
         and DATE_FROM + numToDSInterval( #{interval}, 'second' )
</select>
```